# Couldn't download an URL using curl or wget but it works in browser

Tags: curl, wget, macos, download

I'm trying to download the below URL via terminal:

https://wallpaperaccess.com/download/8k-graphics-4312822

I tried the below methods:

```
curl -L "https://wallpaperaccess.com/download/8k-graphics-4312822" -o 4312822.jpg
```

The downloaded file did not open and looking at the size(4KB) that wasn't surprising.

```
wget --content-disposition "https://wallpaperaccess.com/download/8k-graphics-4312822"
```

403 Forbidden

```
curl -L 'https://wallpaperaccess.com/download/8k-graphics-4312822' \
          -H 'authority: wallpaperaccess.com' \
          -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
          -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
          -H 'cookie: PHPSESSID=****************' \
          -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"' \
          -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
          -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
          -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
          -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
          -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' \
          -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
          -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
          -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36' \
          --compressed > 4312822.jpg
```

Copied from Chrome. Got the same 4KB file but did not open as expected.

But the same URL prompts me for a download in the browser or all download managers I've tested.

Usually, any URL that didn't work with cURL would work after copying from chrome with headers for me. But this time, I can't figure out not why it isn't working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'd recommend actually reading the HTML page you get back: that's cloudflare for you :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I thought copy as cURL would work even with Cloudflare's "I'm Under Attack" mode enabled. Seems like not anymore as it requires more than just agent headers. Wonder how download managers when pasted the URL directly would bypass it though. I have to look into it.

Comment: it's not them bypassing it, pretty certainly. It's cloudflare analyzing typical DDoS tooling behaviour and them ever so slightly behaving differently :) cloudflare is indeed pretty good at what they do :)